# How to convert a vector to a unit vector if its magnitude is smaller than one?

Tags: vector-spaces

In my javascript project, I need to convert a vector to a unit vector. I know that I can divide its x and y components by its magnitude. But what if the vector's magnitude is smaller than one? How to make it a unit vector then ?

Comment: "it's" (abbreviation of "it is") should be $\to$ "its"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same way. Divide by its magnitude. Remember that when you divide by a number that’s less than one, you’re *increasing* the total value.

Comment: Oh I understand. Thanks.

Comment: Minor quibble:  you need to make sure the magnitude is nonzero.

Comment: @BarryCipra yes.

Comment: @BarryCipra True, but one *always* has to check for that. That wasn’t the gist of the question.